# Can’t mount a disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

First of all - I’m a Linux noob, so sorry if I’m missing something obvious.

Today I did a clean reinstall of my pc with W11 and after that I installed Ubuntu in dual boot. So far so good, both OSes are installed on my main SSD and both of them work.

However, I’ve got a second SSD for data, which worked completely fine under Windows 10 and still works completely fine under Windows 11, but somehow in Ubuntu I cannot access it.

I tried to mount the disk, no success, so I decided to do a full format of the disk in Windows. Didn’t help.

The drive in question is a Kingstone 480GB SSD at /dev/sda2. The main SSD can be accessed from Ubuntu just fine.
Here are some logs I gathered:

ntfsfix suggested to run chkdsk, chkdsk in Windows reported no issue with the disk.

Testdisk (I’m not very familiar with how to use it) says something about "number of bytes per sector mismatches 4096 (NTFS) != 512 (HD)" and "The harddisk (480 GB / 447 GiB) seems too small! (< 480 GB / 447 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection..."

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /mnt
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk d: /r
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Data.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  256 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 2.14 milliseconds.
  0 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.25 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 0.47 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  1 reparse records processed.
  278 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 3.82 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 0.46 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 0.86 milliseconds.
  1 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 0.74 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 2.05 milliseconds.
  11 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.40 milliseconds.

Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ...
  240 files processed.
File data verification completed.
 Phase duration (User file recovery): 84.03 milliseconds.

Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
  116593900 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
 Phase duration (Free space recovery): 37.50 minutes.

Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.

 466484200 KB total disk space.
     28088 KB in 8 files.
        72 KB in 13 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
     80436 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 466375604 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 116621050 total allocation units on disk.
 116593901 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 37.50 minutes (2250576 ms).

C:\Windows\system32>
```

```
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0  55,4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop1         7:1    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop2         7:2    0  65,1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop3         7:3    0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop4         7:4    0  32,3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/12704
loop5         7:5    0  55,5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop6         7:6    0  32,5M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop7         7:7    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop8         7:8    0  65,2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
sda           8:0    0 447,1G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0 447,1G  0 part 
nvme0n1     259:0    0 232,9G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 204,1G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0    28G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0   594M  0 part
```

```
sudo fdisk -l
.
.
.
Disk /dev/sda: 447,13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2EE9A682-DFB4-11E9-9792-309C23618171

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  32768 937701375 937668608 447,1G Microsoft Storage Spaces
.
.
.
```

fdisk -l after running mkfs.ntfs on the drive:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 447,13 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk model: KINGSTON SA400S3
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2EE9A682-DFB4-11E9-9792-309C23618171

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     34     32767     32734    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  32768 937701375 937668608 447,1G Microsoft Storage Spaces
```

Does anyone know what might be wrong?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Turn OFF Windows' "Fast Boot" option. "Fast Boot" leaves the disks looking funny.

Comment: Did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As checked your **fdisk -l** output that shows that you partition /dev/sda2 is using **Storage Spaces are based on a new proprietary file system from Microsoft called ReFS (resilient file system)** that might be not support in Linux. So you need change that to type 7 (HPFS/NTFS/exFAT).

```
     fdisk /dev/sda2
      --> t (enter)
      --> 7 (to change the type)
      --> p ( to cross check)
      --> w (to save)
```

Comment: Disabling Fast Boot did not help, and doing a restart of Windows and after that booting right into Ubuntu did not help too unfortunately.

Comment: Once try to format the disk under linux by mkfs.ntfs command and then try to mount it.

Comment: That kinda helped, I can now mount the drive in Ubuntu, but now Windows complains and wants to format the drive.
What about different filesystem than NTFS? There must be a way how to get the drive working under both OSes. I was expecting the main drive to be problematic, not this one.

Comment: Share the output of fdisk -l, after the running mkfs.ntfs on the drive.

Comment: I edited the question and added it.

Comment: @Dom324 change the answer